# Call table-value function in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I created a stored procedure called "CallTableValuedFunctionWithSTRINGParameter". My plan is call a table-valued function from my C# code but I don't find clean to simple create a new `SqlCommand` with the `SELECT * FROM SearchBookFromId(" + bookId + ")"`... So I created a stored procedure that call this table-valued function.

Here the code of the stored procedure. Consider that everything has the `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` and `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` as standard:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CallTableValuedFunctionWithSTRINGParameter
    @functionName VARCHAR(255),
    @parameter VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    RETURN('SELECT * FROM ' + @functionName + '(' + @parameter + ')')
END
```

then I `EXECUTE` it:

```
DECLARE @functionName varchar(255)
DECLARE @parameter varchar(255)

SET @functionName = 'SearchBookFromId'
SET @parameter = '49'

EXECUTE [dbo].[CallTableValuedFunctionWithSTRINGParameter]
   @functionName
  ,@parameter
```

but I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT * FROM SearchBookFromId(49)' to data type int

Here the code of the table-valued function `SearchBookFromId`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SearchBookFromId]
(   
    @bookId VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Books
    WHERE CAST(BookID AS VARCHAR(255)) = @bookId
)
```

`BookID` is an `INT` so I cast it as `VARCHAR`.

The funny thing is that if I try to execute the following code, it works:

```
DECLARE @function VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @parameter VARCHAR(255)

SET @function = 'SearchBookFromId'
SET @parameter = '49'

EXEC('SELECT * FROM ' + @function + '(' + @parameter + ')')
```

Comment: **WARNING** This is wide open to injection attacks. If you "must" use dynamic sql, then properly quote your object names, using `QUOTENAME`, and **parametrise** the statements (which you can't do with `EXEC(@SQL)` syntax, you need to use `sys.sp_executesql`).

Comment: Also, in your function `SearchBookFromId` the `WHERE` clause `CAST(BookID AS VARCHAR(255))  = @bookId` is going to be terrible to performance. Don't `CAST`/`CONVERT` your columns in a `WHERE`; it's not SARGable.

Comment: This, in truth, however, looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Why do you *want* a Procedure to run a TVF? Why does that procedure need to be dynamic? TVF's and Procedures are very difficult object types, and you're effectively removing the point of the TVF by calling it from a Procedure. You can't do something like `SELECT * FROM dbo.CallTableValuedFunctionWithSTRINGParameter N'dbo', N'SearchBookFromId, 7;`

Comment: And `RETURN` in a sproc is always just a single `int` value

Comment: The reason for the `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT * FROM SearchBookFromId(49)' to data type int` error is that `RETURN` expects an integer expression.

Comment: I want it dynamic because I'd like to create something useful for the future too. Like I have this procedure that If I give a function name and a single string parameter to it, it'll execute the function passing this parameter and this function may return a result of a query like SELECT * FROM <a specific table> WHERE <primary key> = @parameter. Something like the concept of an interface in C# plus I want to create clean code and not just passing the SELECT * FROM SearchBookFromId (7) in a new SqlCommand

Comment: *"I want it dynamic because I'd like to create something useful for the future too."* This is going to be far from useful. Trust me. If a user wants to use a function, they'll call that function.

Comment: Well let me understand this then pls. In C# the enum CommandType property in SqlCommand only accept "Stored procedure", "TableDirect" and "Text". So regarding this I should use the Text and call the table-valued function. I'm doing an academy in SQL and my tutor told me this is not clean and I have to create a stored procedure that call a table-value function

Comment: To quote a famous phrase, @Alex95 , "Those who can't, teach."

Comment: Bookmark Erland's site and read his discussion of [TVPs](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html). Your academy / tutor has gone into the deep-end - do not follow.

Comment: Thanks for the article. Now I have to tell something to my tutor that isn't like: I make like this because an user of StackOverflow told me... actually 2 users but still an hard fight and I'm sure he'll win because he's a senior vs a little lamb that would like to learn